# Beginner's snake game using PyGame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, snake-game

I am a complete beginner when it comes to programming and writing games and this is my first ever game. I made it with python 3 using `pygame` library. I would appreciate any feedback really.

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Tuple, List
import pygame
import random
import sys


# screen width & height and block size
bg_width = 500
bg_height = 500
block_size = 10

# direction strings
left = "LEFT"
right = "RIGHT"
up = "UP"
down = "DOWN"

# colors (RGB)
bg_color = black = (0, 0, 0)
yellow = (255, 255, 0)
green = (0, 128, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)

# pygame & font initialization
pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((bg_width, bg_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Snake")
font = pygame.font.SysFont('Times New Roman', 20)
text_colour = pygame.Color('White')
fps = pygame.time.Clock()


class Snake:
    """This class represents a snake object. Every snake object consists of a head
        and its body.
        ===Attributes===
        head: snake head
        color: snake color
        body: snake body
        direction: direction of head
        size: size of snake (head and body)
        """
    head: List[int, int]
    color: Tuple[int, int, int]
    body: List[List[int, int]]
    direction: str
    size: int

    def __init__(self, color: Tuple[int, int, int]) -> None:
        self.head = [int(10*block_size), int(5*block_size)]
        self.color = color
        self.body = [self.head, [9*block_size, 5*block_size]]
        self.direction = right
        self.size = 2

    def change_dir(self, direc: str) -> None:
        if self.direction != left and direc == right:
            self.direction = right
        elif self.direction != right and direc == left:
            self.direction = left
        elif self.direction != down and direc == up:
            self.direction = up
        elif self.direction != up and direc == down:
            self.direction = down

    def move(self) -> None:
        if self.direction == right:
            self.head[0] += block_size
        elif self.direction == left:
            self.head[0] -= block_size
        elif self.direction == up:
            self.head[1] -= block_size
        elif self.direction == down:
            self.head[1] += block_size
        self.body.insert(0, list(self.head))
        self.body.pop()
        if self.body[0] != self.head:
            self.head = self.body[0]

    def add_to_tail(self) -> None:
        new_part = [self.body[-1][0], self.body[-1][1]]
        self.body.append(new_part)
        self.size += 1

    def get_body(self) -> List[List[int, int]]:
        return self.body


class Food:
    """This class represents a food object. Each food object has an x
       and a y value, a color and a state.
       ===Attributes===
       x: x-coordinate of food object
       y: y-coordinate of food object
       color: color of food object
       state: whether food object is on screen or not
       position: x,y-coordinates pair of food object
       """
    x: int
    y: int
    color: Tuple[int, int, int]
    state: bool
    position: Tuple[int, int]

    def __init__(self, color: Tuple[int, int, int]) -> None:
        self.x = random.randint(0, bg_width//block_size - 1)*block_size
        self.y = random.randint(0, bg_height//block_size - 1)*block_size
        self.color = color
        self.state = True
        self.position = self.x, self.y

    def spawn(self) -> Tuple[int, int]:
        if self.state:
            return self.x, self.y
        else:
            self.state = True
            self.x = random.randint(0, bg_width // block_size-1) * block_size
            self.y = random.randint(0, bg_height // block_size-1) * block_size
            return self.x, self.y

    def update(self, state) -> None:
        self.state = state


def collision(snake_: Snake, food_target_x: int, food_target_y: int) -> int:
    snake_rect = pygame.Rect(*snake_.head, block_size, block_size)
    food_rect = pygame.Rect(food_target_x, food_target_y, block_size,
                            block_size)
    if snake_rect == food_rect:
        snake_.add_to_tail()
        return 1
    return 0


def wall_collision(s: Snake) -> bool:
    if (s.head[0] < 0) or (s.head[0] > bg_width-block_size) or (s.head[1] < 0)\
            or (s.head[1] > bg_height-block_size):
        return True
    return False


def game():

    # initialize food and snake
    food = Food(blue)
    snake = Snake(green)

    # initialize loop logic
    running = True
    is_over = False

    # initialize score
    score = 0

    # game loop
    while running:

        # Game over Screen
        while is_over:
            text_on_screen = font.render("You scored: " + str(score) +
                                         ", Press R to play again or Q to quit",
                                         True, text_colour)
            window.blit(text_on_screen, [55, 225])
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                pressed_key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                if pressed_key[pygame.K_q]:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                if pressed_key[pygame.K_r]:
                    game()
            pygame.display.update()

        # check events
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT] or pressed[pygame.K_d]:
                snake.change_dir(right)
            elif pressed[pygame.K_LEFT] or pressed[pygame.K_a]:
                snake.change_dir(left)
            elif pressed[pygame.K_UP] or pressed[pygame.K_w]:
                snake.change_dir(up)
            elif pressed[pygame.K_DOWN] or pressed[pygame.K_s]:
                snake.change_dir(down)

        # fill window and draw snake
        window.fill(black)
        for item in snake.get_body():
            pygame.draw.rect(window, snake.color, [item[0], item[1], block_size,
                                                   block_size])

        # move snake
        snake.move()

        # check for collision with wall:
        collision_with_wall = wall_collision(snake)
        if collision_with_wall:
            is_over = True

        # check if food is still on screen and draw it
        food_pos = food.spawn()
        collision_ = collision(snake, *food_pos)
        if collision_ == 1:
            score += 1
            food.update(False)
        pygame.draw.rect(window, food.color, [food_pos[0], food_pos[1],
                                              block_size, block_size])

        # renders display
        pygame.display.flip()

        # time delay
        pygame.time.delay(60)
        fps.tick(30)

    pygame.quit()
    quit()

game()
```

Comment: It looks good, especially for your first game :)

Comment: I barely know Python: would `body: List [Tuple[int,int]]` be better?  You have XY pairs, not a list of variable-length lists.

Comment: Where did you get the `__future__` package from? I can't install it using PyCharm.

Answer (score 47):

## PEP 8

PEP 8 recommends that constants be written as ["all capital letters with underscores separating words."](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants). So something like:

```
yellow = (255, 255, 0)
```

Should be:

```
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
```

or possibly an `enum` (more on this later)

## Inconsistent quotations

Usually a project will stick with either `""` or `''` unless you have particular reason not to.<sup>1</sup> But for instance:

```
pygame.display.set_caption("Snake")
font = pygame.font.SysFont('Times New Roman', 20)
text_colour = pygame.Color('White')
```

violates the uniformity unnecessarily.

## Enums

To quote the docs on [`enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html):

> An enumeration is a set of symbolic names (members) bound to unique, constant values. Within an enumeration, the members can be compared by identity, and the enumeration itself can be iterated over.

So for instance:

```
left = "LEFT"
right = "RIGHT"
up = "UP"
down = "DOWN"
```

becomes:

```
from enum import Enum
class Direction(Enum):
    LEFT = "LEFT"
    RIGHT = "RIGHT"
    DOWN = "DOWN"
    UP = "UP"
```

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22594360/667648) for more reasons why you should port your stringy code to enums. In addition, there are probably some integer arithmetic tricks you *could* use to eliminate a lot of the `if`-`elif`-`else` chains. (You will need to do some further refactoring to get this to run without error.)

## Unnecessary Comments

Consider:

```
# initialize food and snake
food = Food(blue)
snake = Snake(green)

# initialize loop logic
running = True
is_over = False

# initialize score
score = 0

# game loop
while running:
```

I, personally, would omit all the comments. I could see where a case can be made the game loop comments in the case that someone is trying to understand the code without knowledge of game loops, but I would argue the concept of a game loop is so ubiquitous that those comments get in the way.

If you had to write comments I would instead write:

```
# Initialize entities/data for new game
food = Food(blue)
snake = Snake(green)
score = 0

# Init/start game loop
running = True
is_over = False
while running:
    ...
```

Even then, I'm not quite satisfied with it, but the moral it to not [add redundant comments](https://blog.codinghorror.com/code-tells-you-how-comments-tell-you-why/). However, there may be some debate on this.

The best example is probably:

```
    # move snake
    snake.move()
```

Really think about what this comment contributes.

## Unnecessary assignments

I'm not sure why you wrote:

```
    # check for collision with wall:
    collision_with_wall = wall_collision(snake)
    if collision_with_wall:
        is_over = True
```

When:

```
    if wall_collision(snake):
        is_over = True
```

suffices.

## Add a `main` function

You should consider adding [a `main` function to your project.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20158605/667648) This is usually done through the introduction of:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    game()
```

This allows for me to `import` your project and not have it automatically execute the game function at the bottom. Increasing re-usability.

<sup>1 For instance, It may be the project defaults to `""`, but you need to print out `" Hi "` with the quotes, so `print('" Hi "')` may be chosen.</sup>

Comment: Nice answer!  +1 also for the excellent summary of the `main` function.  That thread you linked to is a great help, but your quick one sentence summary is one of the best TL;DR's I've seen of that.

Comment: In section "Unnecessary assignments" is there reason we would want to do `if wall_collision(snake): is_over = True` instead of `is_over = wall_collision(snake)`?

Comment: @vakus, those are two different things. Perhaps there are many possible checks above that can also set is_over to True, in which case we don't want to set it back to False which your suggested code would do.

Answer (score 24):

In addition to [another answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/221173/201170) I will add these places to improve (I will not repeat all things from that answer, my answer is just an addition):

#### 1. Code inconsistency

You have several places in your code where your code is inconsistent

```
def collision():
...
        return 1
    return 0


def wall_collision():
...
        return True
    return False
```

Both functions are checking collisions but one returns integer (0/1) and another - boolean (True/False).

```
self.head = [int(10*block_size), int(5*block_size)]
self.body = [self.head, [9*block_size, 5*block_size]]
```

For `head` you convert `X*block_size` to int (it is unnecessary anyway). For `body` you don't do it.

I recommend you to always check your code for possible inconsistency.

#### 2. Names inconsistency

I moved it to an another point because it is not about how your code works - it is about how another programmers will read your code.

Look at this two lines:

```
def change_dir(self, direc: str) -> None:
        if self.direction != left and direc == right:
```

You use three different namings for direction entity:

- `dir`
- `direct`
- `direction`

It is **far** better to use consistent variable names. If you are using different direction variables, get them names with only one word for directions. Here is the example:

- `snake_direction`
- `pokemon_direction`
- `some_strange_direction`

or:

- `enemy_dir`
- `arrow_dir`
- `some_another_strange_dir`

#### 3. Small code improvements

Sometimes you look at your code and think: "Hmmm, it is working but looks not good". Often in these cases you can slightly reorganize your code to make it a bit better :)

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    pressed_key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
    if pressed_key[pygame.K_q]:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
```

can be shortened to:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    pressed_key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT or pressed_key[pygame.K_q]:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
```

This line of code is correct too but it is hard to read:

```
if (s.head[0] < 0) or (s.head[0] > bg_width-block_size) or (s.head[1] < 0)\
            or (s.head[1] > bg_height-block_size):
```

But it will be far better to read if you will change it to:

```
if (s.head[0] < 0 or
        s.head[0] > bg_width-block_size or
        s.head[1] < 0 or
        s.head[1] > bg_height-block_size):
```

or even this (sometimes I use it for really long if's):

```
is_wall_collision = any([
    s.head[0] < 0,
    s.head[0] > bg_width-block_size,
    s.head[1] < 0,
    s.head[1] > bg_height-block_size
])
if is_wall_collision:
```

Answer (score 10):

```
    size: int
...

    self.size = 2
```

You never read `size`, and Python Lists already know their own length in case you did need it.

You're just duplicating functionality that `List` already gives you by manually keeping `size` in sync with the list length.

---

**Separate game logic from screen rendering details**

You keep snake coordinates scaled by pixels.  This seems to complicate your code everywhere with `block_size` instead of `1`; I suspect it would be easier to keep snake coordinates in units of blocks, and only scale to pixels for drawing purposes.

e.g. then your outer-wall check could be something like `s.head[0] >= bg_width` instead of
`s.head[0] > bg_width-block_size`.

`1` is special for integers because it's the difference between `>` and `>=`

---

I like your `add_to_tail` idea of putting multiple snake segments in the same place initially, so `move` on future turns actually makes the snake longer on screen.  That high-level design might be worthy of a comment.

The other option would be a "future growth" counter that you check (and decrement) every move to decide whether to remove the last tail block.  (That's what I was expecting because I hadn't thought of your idea).  Your way is more efficient and will still work if you want food to cause multiple segments of growth.  You can still do them all when the food is eaten.

---

Keeping a separate `head`:  I'm not sure this is helping you.  Functions that want to look at the first segment can do `head = snake_.body[0]`.

I don't understand why `move` needs to do this:

```
       if self.body[0] != self.head:
            self.head = self.body[0]
```

when it looks to me like inserting the modified `head` as a new first element will already create that condition.  So either this is redundant (and confusing), or else it's extra work that you wouldn't need to do if you didn't redundantly keep the head coordinates in 2 places.  (Front of the List, and in its own object.)

---

```
    direction: str
```

**This should be an enum or integer, not a string**.  String compares are fairly cheap, but not as cheap as integers.  There's no reason that a direction needs to be an arbitrary string when it can take only 1 of 4 possible values.  A string isn't making your code any easier to read.

You probably still want the if/elif chain to turn a direction into an x or y offset, but another option for an integer would be a lookup table of `[-1, 0]` , `[1, 0]` etc. so you look up the x and y offsets for the given direction and just add them to the head's x and y coordinates without any conditionals.

**Or `direction` could actually *be* an XY vector, removing the lookup step.**

```
    head[0] += direction[0]
    head[1] += direction[1]
```

But that might complicate `change_dir`.  Or give you a different implementation: to check for reversing direction: if `new_dir + old_dir == [0,0]` then you tried to double back.  Otherwise you *can* set `dir = new_dir`.

I like your design for having the keyboard-input just call `change_dir` to check the game-logic of that input.  That works very cleanly, and would still work if `left` was defined as `[-1, 0]` instead of `"LEFT"`.

Answer (score 5):

Good going on your first game. I completely agree with most of the points made by others. Here are a few more nitpicks. This answer is a bit long-winded, but take it as a complement. :-)

### Unpack the Coordinates

This is what lines 195-197 currently look like:

```
        for item in snake.get_body():
            pygame.draw.rect(window, snake.color, [item[0], item[1], block_size,
                                                   block_size])
```

Instead of relying on indexing, we can directly unpack `item` into its respective xy-coordinates. This makes for good brevity and readability.

```
        for x, y in snake.get_body():
            pygame.draw.rect(window, snake.color, [x, y, block_size, block_size])
```

The same can be done for lines 208-214.

```
# Before:
        food_pos = food.spawn()
        collision_ = collision(snake, *food_pos)   # 
        if collision_ == 1:
            score += 1
            food.update(False)
        pygame.draw.rect(window, food.color, [food_pos[0], food_pos[1],  # 
                                              block_size, block_size])


# After:
        food_x, food_y = food.spawn()
        # the rest is left as an exercise for the reader
```

### On `wall_collision(Snake)`

Here's what the `wall_collision` function currently looks like (lines 137-141):

```
def wall_collision(s: Snake) -> bool:
    if (s.head[0] < 0) or (s.head[0] > bg_width-block_size) or (s.head[1] < 0)\
            or (s.head[1] > bg_height-block_size):
        return True
    return False
```

1. Being a predicate (i.e. a function which returns a boolean), the function can be better named. You can always find a way to name a predicate such that it is prefixed with `is` or `has`. Instead of `wall_collision`, I'd go with `is_colliding_with_wall` or `collides_with_wall` to communicate the intention better.
2. It could be simplified. [vurmux's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/221185/197524) suggests a few possible ways. However, there exists an easier (and more readable) way of writing it in one line:

```
    return not ((0 < s.head[0] < bg_width-block_size) and (0 < s.head[1] < bg_height-block_size))
```

<sup>I intentionally added the extraneous parentheses to group comparisons.</sup>

This is made possible by Python's [comparison "chaining"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26502775/pycharm-simplify-chained-comparison/) along with [De Morgan's Laws](https://brilliant.org/wiki/de-morgans-laws/). For fun, you can try to prove that the two snippets are equivalent.

### Points and Coordinates

It took a while for me to figure out what the following line meant:

```
self.head = [int(10*block_size), int(5*block_size)]
```

I'm *guessing* this is a point/coordinate? Looks like it.

Lists are so prevalent in Python, that they can hold a multitude of meanings. What's more, they are *variable-length* constructs, which communicates something else: you might be *changing* the length of the object in the future. This might mean appending, erasing, or inserting into the list.

`self.body` uses a list appropriately, since it will be appended to and popped from in various places. On the other hand, not once does `self.head` use `list.append`, `list.pop`, or `list.insert` and this raises a question: does it need to be a list at all? It is better made a tuple, which is a fixed-length construct and immediately communicates to the reader that we won't be modifying the length of `self.head`.

I commend the usage of tuples in `Food.spawn()` for this very reason. Still, tuples can carry a multitude of different meanings. We can do better by using `collections.namedtuple` and creating a record-type `Point` for the purpose of representing xy-coordinates. This can greatly reduce ambiguity and improve readability.

```
from collections import namedtuple
Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])  # we now have a Point type  

class Snake:
    ...
    def __init__(self, color: Tuple[int, int, int]) -> None:
        self.head = Point(10*block_size, 5*block_size)  # foolproof: self.head is a point      
        self.body = [self.head, Point(...)]
    ...
    def add_to_tail(self) -> None:
        self.body.append(Point(self.body[-1][0], self.body[-1][1]))
        self.size += 1
```

The only pain with namedtuple is that we can't explicitly do assignments, which can be solved by making a new object:

```
def move(self) -> None:
    if self.direction == right:

# Before:
        self.head.x += block_size   # AttributeError: can't set attribute   

# After:
        self.head = Point(self.head.x + block_size, self.head.y)   # preferable
# or:
        self.head = self.head._replace(x=self.head.x + block_size) # looks hacky
```

You can also use `Point` as a replacement for `Food.position`, which isn't being used.

```
class Food:
    ...
    position: Point

    def __init__(self, color: Tuple[int, int, int]) -> None:
        self.position = Point(x=random.randint(0, bg_width//block_size - 1)*block_size
                              y=random.randint(0, bg_width//block_size - 1)*block_size)

    def spawn(self) -> Point:  # more explicit
        if self.state:
            return self.position
        else:
            self.state = True
            self.position = Point(x=random.randint(0, bg_width//block_size - 1)*block_size
                                  y=random.randint(0, bg_width//block_size - 1)*block_size)    
            return self.position
```

I think this is especially useful when used together with [Cordes's suggestion in his answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/221219/197524), in his **Separate game logic from screen rendering details** section.

Another good thing about namedtuple is that we can still do unpacking.

```
        for x, y in snake.get_body():    # still works
            pygame.draw.rect(window, snake.color, [x, y, block_size, block_size])
```

### Refactor Random-Point Generation

There are two places where the coordinates of the food are updated with random integers, generated via a special formula. Based on the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle, I suggest refactoring the generation of random points to a single function `get_random_point()`.

```
def get_random_point():
    return Point(x=random.randint(0, bg_width//block_size - 1)*block_size
                 y=random.randint(0, bg_width//block_size - 1)*block_size)
```

Then you can conveniently do `self.position = get_random_point()` without having to painfully, repetitively type out the above.

### Refactoring `Food`

Currently, `Food` updates its position only when `spawn()` is called and if `state` is false. Seems a bit long-winded. Even the name `update` seems to be untruthful as it makes a *delayed* update.

I suggest updating the position immediately when `update()` is called.

```
    def spawn(self) -> Tuple[int, int]:
        return self.position

    def update(self):
        self.position = get_random_point()
```

Note that `Food.state` and `Food.spawn(self)` are redundant now and can be removed. That should be three cheers (less lines of code, yes?).

### On `collision(Snake, int, int)`

Logically, this section should come first, but I saved it for the last.

1. The name `collision` is ambiguous. Can we improve it? Sure! Note that *logically speaking*, the function returns a boolean, so it's a predicate. Can we prefix it with `is`? Certainly! I think `is_snake_on_food` isn't too bad. You could also go with `is_food_reached` or `is_snake_colliding_with_food`.
2. Having changed how positions are stored in the `Food` class, we can pass in the food's position directly. Thus the signature of the function can be reduced to:

   ```
   def is_snake_on_food(snake: Snake, food_target: Point):
   ```

   This also saves us from needing unpack `*food_pos` in line 209.

   ```
   # Before:
   collision_ = collision(snake, *food_pos)

   # After:
   collision_ = is_snake_on_food(snake, food_pos)
   ```
3. There is no need to create `pygame.Rect` just to compare `snake_.head` and `food_target`. Currently, lines 128-131 are

   ```
       snake_rect = pygame.Rect(*snake_.head, block_size, block_size)
       food_rect = pygame.Rect(food_target_x, food_target_y, block_size,
                               block_size)
       if snake_rect == food_rect:
   ```

   Instead, the coordinates can be compared directly:

   ```
       if (*snake_.head,) == (food_target_x, food_target_y):
   ```

   Having passed in `food_target` as a `Point`, we can simplify this to

   ```
       if snake_.head == food_target:
   ```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the game. I applied most changes suggested by [@Dair](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/82612/dair) and [@vurmux](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/201170/vurmux) as well as partially the suggestions from [@Peter Cordes](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/50567/peter-cordes) (some of them are not so simple). After that, there were still some things left:

#### Game logic

I'm not sure whether it was intentional, but the snake does not collide with itself. In usual snake games, if the snake bites into her tail, the game is over as well.

#### Swallowed keypresses

When playing the game, I noticed that I sometimes cannot perform a U-turn when I needed to. It seems that the first keypress got lost.

The reason is here:

```
pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT] or pressed[pygame.K_d]:
    ...
```

which should be changed to

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_d:
        snake.change_dir(Direction.RIGHT)
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_a:
        snake.change_dir(Direction.LEFT)
    elif event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_w:
        snake.change_dir(Direction.UP)
    elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == pygame.K_s:
        snake.change_dir(Direction.DOWN)
```

However, this brings us to an interesting other problem: doing 2 changes without moving the snake makes the snake run into the opposite direction immediately (without hitting itself as noted before).

Since `pygame.event.get()` consumes all events, it would be up to you, queuing the events yourself and processing them the next frame.

#### High CPU usage when game is over

When the game is over, it uses ~14% CPU time on my machine, which means that 1 core is 100% busy. Adding a `pygame.time.delay(60)` into the `while is_over` loop helps.

#### Classes in files

In addition I tried to apply another principle, which is to have each class in a separate file. Doing so is quite simple with an IDE like Pycharm, since it has the move-refactoring. Unfortunately, it doesn't work any more, because of this:

After the refactoring, Food has

```
from game import bg_width, block_size, bg_height
```

So one's left with a cycle of imports due to the use of global variables. Looking at the food class for possible resolutions, you could pass the necessary dependencies as parameters:

```
def spawn(self, bg_width:int, bg_height:int, block_size:int) -> Tuple[int, int]:
```

After the refactoring, Snake has

```
from game import block_size
```

and a similar solution can apply.

#### Static members

Your classes seem to define the properties twice, once in `__init__` and once as static members. I don't see any usage of the static members, so these can be removed in `Snake`:

```
head: List[int, int]
color: Tuple[int, int, int]
body: List[List[int, int]]
direction: str
size: int
```

and in `Food`:

```
x: int
y: int
color: Tuple[int, int, int]
state: bool
position: Tuple[int, int]
```

#### Naming

Assuming that `bg` is short for *background*, I really wonder whether that's the correct term here. The snake is moving on a board, not on a background I'd say. In the comment for that line, you call it *screen width and height*, which may accidentally be the case as well.

Considering a future version of the game where you add a nice background graphic and display the score below the board, neither *background* nor *screen* would match any more.

#### Code duplication

With the change before, I noticed that there's duplicate code in the Food class. Inside `__init__`, it basically `spawn`s itself.

This duplication can be removed and adding

```
food = Food(BLUE)
food.spawn(bg_width, bg_height, block_size)
```

It can later be discussed whether or not Food needs to be spawned that early.

#### Potential stack overflow in game over mode

Once the game is over, there's a loop handling the situation:

```
while is_over:
```

I expected the game to get out of this loop when a new round begins. However, that's not the case. Instead there is

```
if event.key == pygame.K_r:
    game()
```

This is a recursive call. It's unlikely that it will cause problems in this particular game, but in general, this may cause stack overflows.

It can be resolved by introducing another loop

```
while running:
    while is_over and running:
        ...

    # Initialization code here

    while running and not is_over:
        ...
```

Instead of calling `game()`, you can then set `is_over = False`.

#### Unused variable / unreachable code

The `while running` loop can be replaced by a `while True`, since there's no other assignment to `running` which would terminate the loop.

This also means that the code after `while running` will never be reached:

```
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Changing the exit routine to `running = False`, you save some duplicate code and the code runs to the end. This is e.g. helpful if you later want to implement saving a highscore list etc. If you have many exit points during your program, it will be harder to implement something at the end of the game.

You can also omit `quit()`, because it is not helpful as the last statement of your code.

#### Smaller improvements

`food.update()` is only called with `False` as a parameter. It's never called with `True`. So this argument can be omitted and go hard-coded into the `update()` method. The code then looks like this:

```
while running:
    ...
    food_pos = food.spawn(board_width, board_height, block_size)
    if collision(snake, *food_pos):
        score += 1
        food.update()
```

This reads like the food is spawning in a new place with every frame. IMHO it reads better like this:

```
while running:
    ...
    food_pos = food.??? # whatever 
    if collision(snake, *food_pos):
        score += 1
        food.spawn(board_width, board_height, block_size)
```

Because that makes it clear that food only spaws whenever it collided with the snake aka. it was eaten.

#### Snake direction change

Note: [@Peter Cordes](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/50567/peter-cordes)' vector approach is even more elegant. Perhaps the following might show you a refactoring you can apply in other cases as well when a vector does not fit.

After applying the enum suggestion, the direction check looks like this

```
def change_dir(self, direction: Direction) -> None:
    if self.direction != Direction.LEFT and direction == Direction.RIGHT:
        self.direction = Direction.RIGHT
    elif self.direction != Direction.RIGHT and direction == Direction.LEFT:
        self.direction = Direction.LEFT
    elif self.direction != Direction.DOWN and direction == Direction.UP:
        self.direction = Direction.UP
    elif self.direction != Direction.UP and direction == Direction.DOWN:
        self.direction = Direction.DOWN
```

Combining `self.direction = Direction.RIGHT` and `direction == Direction.RIGHT`, we can simplify

```
self.direction = direction
```

This applies to all 4 cases, so we end up with

```
def change_dir(self, direction: Direction) -> None:
    if self.direction != Direction.LEFT and direction == Direction.RIGHT:
        self.direction = direction
    elif self.direction != Direction.RIGHT and direction == Direction.LEFT:
        self.direction = direction
    elif self.direction != Direction.DOWN and direction == Direction.UP:
        self.direction = direction
    elif self.direction != Direction.UP and direction == Direction.DOWN:
        self.direction = direction
```

Now, we can argue that this is duplicate code and remove the duplication:

```
def change_dir(self, direction: Direction) -> None:
    if (self.direction != Direction.LEFT and direction == Direction.RIGHT) or \
            (self.direction != Direction.RIGHT and direction == Direction.LEFT) or \
            (self.direction != Direction.DOWN and direction == Direction.UP) or \
            (self.direction != Direction.UP and direction == Direction.DOWN):
        self.direction = direction
```

Personally, I'd even prefer

```
def change_dir(self, direction: Direction) -> None:
    if self.is_opposite_direction(direction, self.direction):
        return
    self.direction = direction
```